# Как повесить событие на элемент в iframe c одного домена?

Tags: javascript, iframe

На странице iframe, домен общий.

```
<iframe id="page" src="/" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Пытаюсь повесить событие

```
document.getElementById("page").onload = function() { editor = this.contentWindow.document;
    editor.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
      //тут код события
    });
```

}

В firefox событие срабатывает, в chrome - нет (Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.). Allow-scripts не могу поставить, нужно отключить скрипты в iframe.